# How to pass a string of column name as a parameter into a CREATE TABLE FUNCTION in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to create a table function that takes two arguments, fieldName and parameter, where I can later use this function to create tables in other fieldName and parameter pairs. I tried multiple ways, and it seems like the fieldName(column name) is always parsed as a string in the where clause. Wondering how should I be doing this in the correct way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION dataset.functionName( fieldName ANY TYPE, parameter ANY TYPE)
as
(SELECT *
    FROM `dataset.table` 
    WHERE  format("%t",fieldName ) = parameter 
)
```

Later call the function as

```
SELECT * 
from dataset.functionName( 'passed_qa', 'yes')
```

(passed_qa is a column name and assume it only has 'yes' and 'no' value)

I tried using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, it works, but I just want to know if there's a way to approach this in a functional way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For details see:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions

A work-around can be to use a  `case` statement to select the desired column.  If any column is needed, please use the solution of Mikhail Berlyant.

```
Create or replace table function   Test.HL(fieldName   string,parameter ANY TYPE)
as
(
SELECT *
From (   select "1" as tmp, 2 as passed_qa) # generate dummy table
Where case 
    when fieldName="passed_qa" then format("%t",passed_qa)
    when fieldName="tmp" then format("%t",tmp)
    else ERROR(concat('column ',fieldName,' not found')) end = parameter
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Good news - **IT IS POSSIBLE!!!** (*side note: in my experience - i haven't had any cases when something was not possible to achieve in BigQuery directly or indirectly/workaround* maybe with some few exceptions)

See example below

```
create or replace table function dataset.functionName(fieldName any type, parameter any type)
as (
select * from `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area` t
where exists ( select true
    from unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(to_json_string(t))) key with offset
    join unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_values`(to_json_string(t))) value with offset
    using(offset)
    where key = fieldName and value = parameter
  )
)
```

Now, when table function created - run below as see result

```
select * 
from dataset.functionName('state_abbreviation', 'GU')
```

you will get record for GUAM

[image]

Then try below

```
select * 
from dataset.functionName('division_code', '0')
```

with output

[image]